# Python comparing two same string returns with false

Tags: python, string, comparison

I'll put some of my code bellow to explain the issue, but basically what I'm trying to do it to compare within a function - a string & a line that will include only that string.

I have the list as follows:

```
org_tasks = ['general_static ', 'host_general_static ',etc....]
```

which I'm passing to function with a filename (python file)

```
my_dict = createDictFromTaskList(ref_ver, org_tasks) 

def createDictFromTaskList(prm_fl,tasks_list): 
    final_dict = {}
    for task in tasks_list:
        print getTransformedDic(prm_fl, str('CurrentTaskParams.' + task))
    return final_dict
```

which calls:

```
def getTransformedDic(prm_fl,dic_name): # transforms string to dictionary 
    "turns dictionary values from type variable into a string"
    newDic = ""
    dicToChange = getOldDicAsString(prm_fl,dic_name)
    if dicToChange is None: return None 
    dicToChange = dicToChange[len(dic_name) + 3:] #here i get none for some reason 
    dicToChange = dicToChange.replace('"', "'")
    for line in dicToChange.splitlines():
        transformedLine = ''.join(line.split())
        transformedLine = transformedLine.strip()
        if transformedLine.startswith('#'): continue
        IsLineBelongsToDic = transformedLine.split(':')
        if len(IsLineBelongsToDic) > 1:
            if transformedLine[-1:] == ",":
                valueAsString = '"%s",' % transformedLine[len(IsLineBelongsToDic[0]) + 1:-1]
            else:
                valueAsString = '"%s",' % transformedLine[len(IsLineBelongsToDic[0]) + 1:]
            line = '    ' + IsLineBelongsToDic[0] + ' : ' + valueAsString
        newDic += '%s' % line + '\n'
    try:
        value = ast.literal_eval(newDic[:-1])
    except SyntaxError:
        return None
    else:
        return value


def getOldDicAsString(prm_fl, dic_name): 
    "return a string that contains dictionary"
    with open(prm_fl) as f:
        file_data = f.read()
    recordLines = False
    dictionary = ""
    for line in file_data.splitlines():
        transformedLine = ''.join(line.split())
        transformedLine = transformedLine.strip()
        taskName = transformedLine.split('=')[0]
        print taskName ,dic_name # here i can see they are the same 
        if taskName == dic_name or recordLines:
            recordLines = True
            dictionary += line + '\n'
            if transformedLine == "}":
                return dictionary
```

the file i work with looks as follows (according to list I've mentioned before):

```
...
CurrentTaskParams.general_static = {
     'is_enable'         :         'true'
}
CurrentTaskParams.host_general_static = {
     'is_enable'         :         'true'
}
...
```

after adding few prints I've seen that when for example I compare

> CurrentTaskParams.general_static

--> which was passed as parameter

to the line containing this string (after striping in from spaces & '{' & '=' )
I dont append the dictionary string (meaning my 'if' returns false)

any help would be great,
thanks!

Comment: With a minimal example and a more concise question it is easier to get an answer. I suggest you to edit the question making it simpler

Comment: What is the purpose of `if taskName == dic_name or recordLines:` when `recordLines` is always `False`?

Comment: Is the space at the end of the strings of the `org_tasks` list present also on your script or is just a mistake in this post? You should remove it since you are removing all the spaces from the file's lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following minimal example replicates your source data and your code block:

```
file_data = """
CurrentTaskParams.general_static = {
     'is_enable'         :         'true'
}
CurrentTaskParams.host_general_static = {
     'is_enable'         :         'true'
}
"""

dic_name = 'CurrentTaskParams.general_static'

for line in file_data.splitlines():
    transformedLine = ''.join(line.split())
    transformedLine = transformedLine.strip()
    taskName = transformedLine.split('=')[0]
    print("'%s'" % taskName, "'%s'" % dic_name, taskName == dic_name)
```

Running this it correctly picks up the line in question:

```
'' 'CurrentTaskParams.general_static' False
'CurrentTaskParams.general_static' 'CurrentTaskParams.general_static' True
''is_enable':'true'' 'CurrentTaskParams.general_static' False
'}' 'CurrentTaskParams.general_static' False
'CurrentTaskParams.host_general_static' 'CurrentTaskParams.general_static' False
''is_enable':'true'' 'CurrentTaskParams.general_static' False
'}' 'CurrentTaskParams.general_static' False
```

With a working example it is difficult to debug the problem(!) but I suspect this means the problem is somewhere else.

In your example code you list the org tasks with the trailing space still in place, is this intentional?

```
org_tasks = ['general_static ', 'host_general_static ',etc....]
```

I would suggest you try printing the data you believe to be matching but wrapped in quotes (see above) as this will help better highlight any leading/trailing spaces in your strings.

Comment: actually the space shouldnt be there, & after removing it - problem solved!